# pip not finding setup file

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I am getting an error when trying to install a python package with pip.

It is looking in a certain directory for "setup.py" after untaring the package and it can't find it there.  The setup.py file is actually one directory down.

It's looking in:

```
 'virtualenvs/pyling/build/nltk/setup.py'
```

but it's actually in:

```
virtualenvs/pyling $ ls build/nltk/nltk-2.0b9/
INSTALL.txt  javasrc  LICENSE.txt  nltk  PKG-INFO  README.txt  setup.py
```

Is there a way to make pip aware of this nested folder structure in the package?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you know you can untar it, and run `python setup.py install` yourself?

Comment: yes, i am aware of that.  it's just that i would rather use pip out of box so that i can use pip freeze for a requirements file as well as making a bundle to share with others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added a little function and call it in the property definition for setup_py in the pip/req.py file.

this seems to make it work the way i expect, that is if the setup.py file is only one layer deeper.  hopefully nothing gets busted when bundling and freezing...

```
import os

def get_setup_path(in_path):
    print "starting path is %s"%in_path
    fileList=os.listdir(in_path)
    if fileList.__contains__("setup.py"):
        print "setup.py is indeed there"
        return in_path
    for f in fileList:
        f=os.path.join(in_path,f)
        if os.path.isdir(f):
            contents=os.listdir(f)
            if contents.__contains__("setup.py"):
                out_path=os.path.join(in_path,f)
                return out_path
    print "could not find setup.py by looking one level deeper"
    return in_path
```

and then call it here in req.py

```
(around line 195 in req.py)
@property   
def setup_py(self):
     self.source_dir= get_setup_path(self.source_dir)
     return os.path.join(self.source_dir, 'setup.py')
```

Answer (score 1):

What I found was that pip runs a python command line script that looks like this:

```
__file__ = '<path to package>/setup.py'

from setuptools.command import egg_info

def replacement_run(self):
    self.mkpath(self.egg_info)

    installer = self.distribution.fetch_build_egg

    for ep in egg_info.iter_entry_points('egg_info.writers'):
        # require=False is the change we're making:

        writer = ep.load(require=False)

        if writer:
            writer(self, ep.name, egg_info.os.path.join(self.egg_info,ep.name))

    self.find_sources()

egg_info.egg_info.run = replacement_run

execfile(__file__)
```

In the package's top level directory, where there was no setup.py, I placed a setup.py that reproduced this behaviour, but chdir'd to the directory that contained the "real" setup.py and executed that at the end instead.

The only other issue was that pip creates a directory "pip-egg-info" which it expects to be populated, requiring a symbolic link to be created to it in the directory with the "real" setup.py.

The new, top level setup.py looks like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from os import chdir, symlink, getcwd
from os.path import join, basename, exists

filename = basename(__file__)

chdir("python")

setupdir = getcwd()

egginfo = "pip-egg-info"

if not exists(egginfo) and exists(join("..", egginfo)):
    symlink(join("..", egginfo), egginfo)

__file__ = join(setupdir, filename)

from setuptools.command import egg_info

def replacement_run(self):
    self.mkpath(self.egg_info)

    installer = self.distribution.fetch_build_egg

    for ep in egg_info.iter_entry_points('egg_info.writers'):
        # require=False is the change we're making:

        writer = ep.load(require=False)

        if writer:
            writer(self, ep.name, egg_info.os.path.join(self.egg_info,ep.name))

    self.find_sources()

egg_info.egg_info.run = replacement_run

execfile(__file__)
```

It's probably brittle, but should continue to work until pip changes the command line python code that it's generating

Answer (score 0):

- fix the package to follow a standard package layout i.e., `setup.py` should be in a top directory.

or

- untar the archive and point `pip` to a directory with the `setup.py` file.

Comment: my solution allows me to do one step pip installs prior to downloading anything so that is what i prefer.  freeze still seems to work but haven't bundled yet, assuming it will be fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

I already had this problem when calling pip from a directory different from the one the setup.py is in. The solution was adding the following to setup.py:

import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(`__file__`)))

Maybe you call pip from virtualenvs/pyling/build/nltk/ where it should be virtualenvs/pyling/build/nltk/nltk-2.0b9/ ? Then just add what I did.

Comment: i'd like to be able to call pip from any directory when in my targeted virtualenv.  the package is not even downloaded or unpacked yet most of the time so there is no setup.py file yet.

Comment: This can be done by either executing: source /path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/activate (necessary only once per opened shell) AND pip install /path/to/package OR /path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/pip /path/to/package

Comment: yes i am already activated at the point in question.  i see your point about the path but if the package is not yet downloaded (which pip does for you) then there is no path to refer to yet.  i guess i wanted it to work in one step not 2 by using the --dowload-only option and then installing as a second step.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and gave up on using the default URL for pip. However, if you just want to install nltk, this works for me:

```
pip install -E <virtualenv-dir> PyYAML #if you have not done so
pip install -E <virtualenv-dir> --no-index --find-links=http://nltk.googlecode.com/ nltk
```